# Adding labels to legend post plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have to plot 2 lines and then measure the absolute distance between them. This distance then becomes the label for the legend.
Pseudo Code looks something like this:

```
for line in file:
    # extract data here
    sample = sns.kdeplot(data)
    perfect_template = sns.kdeplot(perfect_template_data)
    sample_line = sample.get_lines()[iterate].get_data()
    perfect_line = perfect_template.get_lines()[iterate]get_data()
    absolute_diff = sum(abs(np.diff(zip(sample_line, perfect_line))))
    label = absolute_diff
    sample = sns.kdeplot(data, linewidth=1, label=label)
    plt(legend)
pp.savefig()
```

This requires me to plot `sns.kdeplot` twice.
Is there a way to add the label to the initial `sns.kdeplot` without re-plotting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set_label()` like this:

```
sample.set_label(label)
```

I.e. for a minimal example:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.sin(2*x)

first_line,  = plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y2)

first_line.set_label('First line')

plt.legend()
```

Comment: The sns.kdeplot() is apparently not iterable (so has nothing to plot the label to). Is there anyway to force it to be iterable?

Comment: That was my example matplotlib code. In your own code, you already extract a line object and name it `sample_line` so use that, not my code.

Comment: Sorry. Ignore that. `TypeError: 'Line2D' object is not iterable`. What was meant (when using correct code).

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Did `sample_line.set_label()` work or not? If it did, feel free to mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks.